# How to Dynamically Increase Active Tasks in Spark running on Yarn

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn

[image]I am running a spark streaming process where I got a batch of 6000 events.  But when I look at executors only one active task is running.  I tried dynamic allocation and as well as setting number of executors etc.  Even if I have 15 executors only one active task is running at a time.  Can any one please guide me what am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're having only one partition in your `DStream`. You should try to explicitly repartition your input stream:

```
val input: DStream[...] = ...
val partitionedInput = input.repartition(numPartitions = 16)
```

This way you would have 16 partitions in your input `DStream`, and each of those partitions could be processed in a separate task (and each of those tasks could be executed on a separate executor)

Comment: Thanks so much for your response Pawel.  I had already set number of partitions as 40 in this case.  I have been struggling with this for sometime any help or guidance is very much appreciated.  Excerpt from my code: JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                 ...
            );
            String partitionSize = contextVal.getString(KAFKA_PARTITION);
            if(partitionSize != null){
             int repartitionSize = Integer.parseInt(partitionSize);
             messages.repartition(repartitionSize);
            }

Comment: When you're on "Jobs" tab in Spark UI, how many tasks are shown for the job you're trying to execute?

Comment: I see only one Active Job and number of Completed Jobs

Comment: Could you edit your original post and show a screenshot of your "Jobs" tab?

Comment: I have also added spark.streaming.concurrentJobs to 18

Comment: Could you edit your post and provide more detailed example of your code? In the excerpt you've pasted I see that you're using `repartition` method, but you're not assigning the result to any variable. Since DStreams are immutable, that statement is useless (it effectively makes a new repartitioned instance, but it's never used). Of course your full code might be already using it somehow, that's why it would be nice to see more comprehensive example. By the way you didn't have to remove your previous screenshots, all of them are useful in situations like that ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115345/discussion-between-alchemist-and-pawel-jurczenko).

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH Pawel!! You are right I was not reassigning repartition method to a variable.  I followed your hint and it worked.  Thanks again a lot!!

Comment: Glad to hear that ;)

Comment: Thanks so much Pawel for your time and help with this issue.  Your timely help is greatly appreciated.